# tee: What exactly does "--ignore-interrupts" option do?

Tags: linux, tee

The title basically says it all. *tee* has an option *--ignore-interrupts*:

```
-i, --ignore-interrupts   ignore interrupt signals
```

Can anyone explain/give an example in which situation this is important? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When called with `-i`, `tee` ignores the interrupt signal (`SIGINT`), which is normally issued by your terminal when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: And in which situation this is important?

Comment: If you're using `tee` in a command line pipe like `some long running command | tee output`, this might be helpful if you want to kill the input provider with `Ctrl+C`, but want `tee` to exit gracefully (by reading `EOF` from the pipe).

Comment: Ah, very useful and a nice description, I was a little irritated. Now I'll add it to some of my scripts. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasWiese: You should add your comment to your answer.

Comment: I still don't get it. I have a long running command.  I ran it with and without the `-i` option and did a Ctrl+C both times.  The output file was identical.  What's the point of this.

Comment: One point is avoiding race conditions. Everybody in the pipeline is supposed to get the SIGINT, but tee gets it first while process feeding it gets an error from the broken pipe before it gets around to handling its SIGINT and you got a mess. I would ask the opposite question: when would you ever want tee to receive SIGINT and potentially produce a race condition? Any way, if your process feeding tee has a SIGINT handler, it's likely you really want that tee -i option turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If `tee` is used with `-i, --ignore-interrupts` options, It wont accept any interrupt signals like CNTRL+C ^C or Kill signals Except signal KILL or Signal Terminate.

Comment: That's not quite right; `tee` does _exactly_ what the option states and only ignores `SIGINT`.  All other signals are delivered as without `-i`.